# Bootstrap 4 popper moves top-left corbner on scroll or window resize

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4, popper.js

In our new admin page with datatables and bootstrap4, we heve implemented a poper for each row. It works perfect on most cases. When we scroll or window is resized, the popper moves to top left corner and stays there.

I have tried all possible configurations like removing all possible configurations and inner componentes for the button.

```html
<a data-id="' + data + '" data-toggle="popper"
       data-title="Are you sure?" data-content="This will not be visible on website!">
 <i title="Disable Item" data-toggle="tooltip" class="nav-icon i-Power-2 rounded-circle"></i>
</a>
```

I use fnDrawCallback of datatables to initialize popper.

```
fnDrawCallback: function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popper"]').popover({
        container: "body",
    });
}
```

HTML code for popper when it is on correct position

```html
<div 
    class="popover fade show bs-popover-left" 
    role="tooltip" 
    id="popover230546" 
    x-placement="left" 
    style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(880px, 556px, 0px);">

    <div class="arrow" style="top: 28px;"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-header">Are you sure?</h3>
    <div class="popover-body">"This will not be visible on website!</div>
</div>
```

HTML after jumping to top left

```html
<div 
    class="popover fade show bs-popover-right" 
    role="tooltip" 
    id="popover230546" 
    x-placement="left" 
    style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(5px, 481px, 0px);">

    <div class="arrow" style="top: 28px;"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-header">Are you sure?</h3>
    <div class="popover-body">"This will not be visible on website!</div>
</div>
```

**Observation**
In bootstrap 3 implementation, the popper is inserted as element near the triggering anchor/row, where as in Bootstrap 4, the popper is inserted as last element in the body.

How can I make it stick to the trigger link/row?

Comment: Another observation: Sometimes, when I mouseover the original element (anchor tag) that triggered the popper, the popper comes back to the desired position!

Comment: have you got a solution?